# Netlogo GIS unsupported shape type file

Tags: gis, netlogo

During the SETUP loading phase of shp files of an urban model, Netlogo states:

```
Extension exception: unsupported shape type 15
error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET
called by procedure SETUP
called by Button 'Go'
```

This happens when it tries to load this shp file: [ZC.shp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/32vlhr0onkpdqko/ZC.zip?dl=0)

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Does the shapefile have routing or elevation data associated with it? If so, you'll have to strip that data from the file to use it if I remember correctly.

Comment: I have saved the file again but without z-axis information, and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have saved the shp file again but without z-axis information, and it worked